# MySQLi return an array with bind_result and fetch not working

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli, php-5.3

I was wondering how to rewrite/fix the following code.

Basically, I have a database named `DB` and a table in it called `poems`. I want to get all the data in the `poems` table that has a certain ID (i.e. who wrote the poem, the tags it has, its content, when it was created, etc.) and securely store it in an array to later be printed out onto a web page.

The hosting service I have doesn't have support for the mysqlnd driver needed for `mysqli_getresult()`, so I currently get the error "`Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()`"

`$mysqli` is a pre-written connection to the database, using `new mysqli()`

```
function getpoemdata($mysqli) {
                echo "Function started.";
                if(isset($_GET['poem_id'])) { // Check if poem_id is set in the URL
                    $poemid=$_GET['poem_id']; // Get poem_id set in URL
                    if (!is_int($poemid)) { $poemid = 7; } // Check if poem_id is set an integer
                    if ($poemid <= 0) { $poemid = 7; } //Check if poem_id is positive- If negative, it is changed to positive
                    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `poems` WHERE `poem_id` = ?");
                    $stmt->bind_param('i', $poemid);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $result = $stmt->get_result();
                    $returned_data = $returned_data->fetch_array();
                    while($stmt->fetch()){
                        echo $returned_data . '<br />';
                    }
                    $stmt->free_result();
                }
                else { //If user simply types "poemview.php" and not "poemview.php?poem_id="
                echo "error";
            }
    }
```

Thank you a ton in advance for any help- I'm pretty new to PHP and trying to learn it as I go along- it's just a little overwhelming everytime I try to do something new and need to learn a dozen more functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_result()` was introduced in PHP 5.3.0 and, as mentioned, requires *mysqlnd*. However, I don't think you need it. You can use [fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) in combination with `bind_result` to retrieve the data. There may be other ways as well.

Example from the docs:

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 150,5";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    /* execute statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $code);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $name, $code);
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

An example further down in the docs shows how to bind to an array.